# Javascript parseFloat 10 instead of e

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

Im using parseFloat on very high numbers or very low numbers.
The return value is like 123*10e15 , I need to be like 123*10^15 . 15 needs to be in upper writing as a pow.
Thanks.

Comment: Um, so what part of the conversion is giving you trouble? This seems like a straightforward textual substitution.

Comment: I think you mean `123e15`, **not** `123*19e15`.

Comment: `1230000000000000000` your desired output ?

Comment: `parseFloat` parses `string` to floating point `number`. So the return value is `number`. `123*10e15` is `string` that represents `number`.

Comment: please look at Amadans answer and understand what i wanted.

Answer (score 5):

`parseFloat` turns a string into a number. A number has no "format"; it gets turned back into a string (by `Float`'s method `toString`) when you display it. If you want to display it with a caret, you will need to format (or reformat) it yourself into a string: easiest like this:

```
123e45.toString().replace('e', '*10^')     // result: "1.23*10^+47"
```

(if the `+` bugs you, you can try this, using a regexp:)

```
123e-45.toString().replace(/e\+?/, '*10^') // result: "1.23*10^47"
```

Comment: good, that solves the replacement , now..how can i make the 45 an upper text like pow?

Comment: Are you now talking about HTML? `.replace(/e([+-]?\d+)/, '*10<sup>$1</sup>')`. If you're not talking about HTML, then you probably can't.